# Support information in backend

Tags: plugins

Is it possible to display a support information box in the backend? For example, for specific users? Like mail, telephone number, and so on? Similar to the "Welcome to WordPress!" box.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: I recommend you to read [The Dashboard Widgets API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) which makes it very simple to add new widgets to the administration dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at custom dashboard widget usage :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-dashboard-widgets-in-wordpress/

http://wpengineer.com/307/add-wordpress-dashboard-widgets/

I have included the code you need copied from the reference link 3rd link which will allow you to add a custom dashboard widget.

Add this to your functions.php and customise as you wish.

```
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_custom_dashboard_widgets');

function my_custom_dashboard_widgets() {
global $wp_meta_boxes;

wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Theme Support', 'custom_dashboard_help');
}

function custom_dashboard_help() {
echo '<p>Welcome to Custom Blog Theme! Need help? Contact the developer <a href="mailto:yourusername@gmail.com">here</a>. For WordPress Tutorials visit: <a href="http://www.wpbeginner.com" target="_blank">WPBeginner</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: RTFM is not a real answer :(

Comment: Providing the manuals and references to step by step how to's should be enough.  But point taken, i have added a code snippet as well.